# There seems to be a logic problem with continued showing of the "Take our survey" banner after I've taken it?

Tags: bug

Today we are presented with the "Take our survey" banner:

[image]

However, after dutifully taking the survey, I am being continually presented with the same take survey banner on SO. When I go to the top-questions list, it is gone, but as soon as I select a question from the list and go to its page -- the banner reappears. Is there a logic issue that should disable the banner after the survey is taken that is not working?

Browser is FF 60.8esr

Comment: Related: *[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)*. ESR 60: [2018-05-09](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Firefox_60_through_67)